# Accidently grabbed a vertex from a uv sphere and now I cannot deselect it

Tags: objects, selection-tools, vertex-groups, select

I cannot deselect the vertex from this uv sphere, and I've done this before, why isn't it deselecting it now?

I'm building an egg and an egg lock from a comic book, but I selected the vertices on the egg to rip some out, and a single vertex from this sphere won't let me deselect it at all, I've done this before, why won't it allow me to deselect this single vertex?

I cannot undo this mistake when I've done it before, and it continues to do it, selecting each vertex individually would be a horror show, but doable, so what changed on me and how can I make sure it doesn't come back to haunt me.

Yes, I know I can take the sphere out of view, but that doesn't do me the solid of deselecting this vertex I need unselected, which is all I'm curious about.

Comment: Alt-A should deselect everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "box select mode", drawing the box while holding Ctrl will deselect everything inside. Hope that helps

Comment: yeah, I managed, I was just wondering what made the vertex un-deselctable on it's own. I was trying to specifically Not select the orb, I just forgot to renove the sphere from view, but I was wondering about that one mechanic, maybe object activation order that locked it in, or accidently activating the second obj switched my 3d viewport mode. Just curious as to what stopped that single vertex from being unselectable. I tried box and circle deselect, it would deselect the vertices around it, just not that single bottom vertex, curious as to the interaction that stopped its deselection. Thanks